# A little more - a little bit more

Tags: word-choice, difference

Which one is the correct one for my sentence? Why?

> If I were you, I'd ask your parents to trust you **a little more** / **a little bit more** and reach a compromise.

Comment: They are both correct, but 'a little more' is slightly more formal than 'a little bit more'.

Comment: Hello Simo Ita and welcome to ELL! We have a rule here against asking two questions in one. If you'd really like the answer to both questions, please use the "Ask Question" button to ask separately about about "reach" or "to reach". I'm removing your second question.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know gotube. 

Answer (score 1):

> If I were you, I'd ask your parents to trust you a little more / a little bit more and reach a compromise.

Yes, as @Michael Harvey has commented,
*a little more* is more formal than *a little bit more*.

[onlineteachersuk](https://onlineteachersuk.com/adverbs-of-degree/) gives examples on the use of **a little bit**, **a bit**, and **a little**.

> 36 Adverbs of degree: A-Z list with examples

> A (little) bit (informal)
> He arrived a little bit late.
> I’m a bit worried about Tom.

> I feel a little tired.
> He looked a little confused.